# Queries about Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a student residing in Kerala. My husband works as a Doctor in Germany, and I wish to visit him for a period of two weeks.

1. Is it enough that I show his bank statements of the last 6 months and his salary slips? In addition to this should I also show my bank balance? That is I show that my husband is sponsoring my entire trip.
2. Should I apply for visa in Bangalore Embassy or could I apply at Cochin?

Comment: What's your husband's nationality? And if he isn't an EU citizen, what visa is he on in Germany?

Comment: Another potentially useful bit of information is what is your nationality.

Comment: Can you provide us with information about the nationality of both of you, also how long he has been working in Germany and maybe the type of visa he is on (if he isn't a EU national).

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for the visa in [either Kochi or Bangalore](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/Bangalore/index.html) for the Karnataka & Kerala visa region. Regardless of your citizenship (unless you are an EU citizen, then you don't need a visa) you have to apply in the country of your residence (work or studies), so you need to apply in India (and in Kochi or Bangalore since that is where your regional offices are).

There are a [list of documents required](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/Bangalore/touristfamilyfriends_vist_documentsrequired.html) for **Visiting Family & Friends** in Germany which you can see [here](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/Bangalore/pdf/checklist_c_visit_19.11.13.pdf).

You would require the following, please see [this list for the required documents](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/Bangalore/pdf/checklist_c_visit_19.11.13.pdf):

> - **Proof of accommodation** for your entire stay in the Schengen area
> - **Proof of sufficient funds** for the visit:
>
>   - **If sponsored: Verpflichtungserklärung** (formal obligation letter) of your sponsor
> - **Proof of civil status:** Marriage certificate, birth certificate of children, death certificate of spouse, ration card if applicable

It may also help to provide more information:

- His bank statements (seems like last 3 months should be sufficient, but last 6 months won't hurt)
- Proof of his employment
- Proof of you being a student

Also the German Embassy or Consulate may require additional documentation, that is not on their list of required documents.

There is an [unofficial list of the additional documentation](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/documents.html). Also there is a [unofficial list of the proof of subsistence required for Germany](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/means-of-substinence.html).